# Delphi-5 single-file storage solution?

Tags: delphi, storage, delphi-5, single-file

Is there a Delphi-5 solution to easily integrate single-file storage into existing code? I would like to have files like Java *.jar or Openoffice document files which are zipped/compressed files and folders but with their own file extension.

**Edit:**
I know some ZIP capable components but in a nutshell I want to access files within the "container" and use normal file handling routines on them (eg. TStringList.SaveToFile). Any overhead about compress/uncompress should be handled by the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [AidAim Software](http://www.aidaim.com/single-file_delphi_virtual_file_system.htm) might have what you need.

Comment: although I don't like AidAim it's still a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use the .zip format.  You can change the file extension to whatever you want, its the file contents that are important. There are many third-party Zip solutions available for Delphi, both freeware and commercial.  Look around (my company uses [ZipForge](http://www.componentace.com))

Comment: I am looking for some out-of-the box solution which would be transparent to existing legacy applications since I already know about the different .zip components. In a nutshell I want to have a files within the single-file-storage and use normal file handling routines on them (eg. TStringList.SaveToFile) - I don't want to be bothered with the compress/uncompress by myself.

Comment: You would have to find a .zip component that supports reading/writing files as TStream objects, and then change your code to use SaveToStream() instead of SaveToFile().  The only way I know to SaveToFile() into a .zip file directly is to first mount the .zip file as a file system folder at the OS level, such as with WinXP's Compressed Folders feature, or a third-party Shell Extension plugin that uses the .zip format internally.

Answer (score 1):

I use THKStream for this task. It works good and fast and is easy to use, you can store normal Streams in it and it compresses them to a single file. Freeware. Here is a Link: 
http://www.xarka.com/freeware/components.html

Answer (score 0):

[SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/delphi-single-file-system.php) is the answer. Check the link for comparison with AidAim.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [OpenSource SynZip unit](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=48). It's even faster for decompression than the default unit shipped with Delphi, and it will generate a smaller exe (crc tables are created at startup).

For Delphi 5, take a look at this another Open Source pure pascal unit, named [PasZip](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=PasZip.pas).

I use it in very small installer exe. It can uncompress any zip content, and you can even append the zip to the exe. See [this link to get how to use such a zip embedded to the exe](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=232#p232).